# In WooCommerce, can I make “shopping cart” appear only in SHOP section and when a customer actually adds an item in cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I’m using Nikkon on Wordpress and would like the shopping icon to show only in shop section and after customer has added an item, kind of like how Squarespace does it. Is it possible? I used the following code in CSS edit but it did nothing:

```
.home .top-login,
.home .top-cart {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, 

When asking here, please add some code you have tried, or some reference from your code so we can refer to it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, just did! :)

Comment: I checked this theme: https://demo.kairaweb.com/#nikkon , I hope I checked the right one. I think it can't be a pure CSS solution. But you will need to get jQuery assistant here to identify if the cart has items and to show it accordingly